# What is the most jquery-compatible and easy-to-use color picker for jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, color-picker

I'm looking for something like that resembles a color picker that windows or adobe products often use. Which one is popular, well-supported, easy-to-use and hopefully works well with jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use this [jPicker](http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/).